About these demons from Mahabharata
This chapter of Santi Parva from Mahabharata mentions the demons who have corrupted people's righteousness with sins and then Lord Shiva destroys them with their leader.

Having achieved great progress in righteousness, men in those days worshipped only all good qualities that they saw. The Asuras, however, O child, could not bear that righteousness which prevailed in the world. Multiplying (in both number and energy), the Asuras (in the form of Lust and Wrath) entered the bodies of men. Then was pride generated in men that is so destructive of righteousness.


The fierce chief of those Asuras possessed of fierce, prowess, who had struck the Devas with terror, was also slain by Mahadeva armed with the lance. When this chief of the Asuras was slain, men once more obtained their proper natures, and once more began to study the Vedas and the other scriptures as was in former times.

It is interesting. However, do any other scriptures provide some other details (ex. Their family lineage) about the demons and/or their leader?
